# When "you" is being used as a dummy subject

Tags: subjects, conversation

I observe very often that in conversations, native speakers say "you" as a dummy subject (not sure if that's a correct way to call it), not particularly meaning the person whom the speaker is talking to.

For example,
"What the text mainly discusses in this chapter is, when you are poor, you are likely to choose bad dietary options."

My question is, how do native speakers exactly interpret "you" in conversations?

Also, I think it would be rude to say the above, when the speaker is talking to an actually poor person, knowing the listener is poor, even though "you" in the sentence doesn't mean the poor person. Then, do they phrase in a different way to avoid the use of "you"?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always paraphrase it using "one": When one's poor, one's likely to choose bad dietary options.

Comment: @IrethTasartir nails it, I think. _You_ is interpreted as _one_. About the rudeness, that depends largely on context, rather than the use of _one_. If you want to tell someone they are eating badly, the example sentence is indeed quite a rude way to say it, but as a general observation, it's fine.

Comment: There is a world of difference between "When you are poor" (general statement) and "When you were in my car yesterday" (specific statement). Native speakers make the switch automatically and instantaneously.

Comment: Although there have been times when it was not clear to me whether the speaker meant "me" or "one".

Comment: But "one" isn't always appropriate, it's rather formal and would come across as affected in some situations.

Comment: @ChrisH - I can't think of a situation where using 'one' would be / seem incorrect.   Care to elaborate...?

Comment: @MrWonderful: incorrect - no. Overly formal, old fashioned - yes. Especially in speech.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it was 9th grade English class where I had to learn to use 'one' as a non-specific subject.

While most formal writing likewise uses 'one,' I have continued to use 'one' in casual conversation as well, as it just seemed more 'right' to me.

> "One need only listen closely to hear the surf."

or

> "What the text mainly discusses in this chapter is, when one is poor, one is likely to choose bad dietary options."

Because I inferred that using 'one' was more 'correct,' I adopted it into my everyday conversation style.  Although using 'you' is easily understood to be effectively synonymous, I tend to avoid it, even in conversation.

But, ultimately, 'you' is translated to mean 'one' when used, unless obviously directed to the 2nd party of the conversation.